# Working string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, string

I have the following string in MATLAB, for example

> @#%%F1_USA(40)_u

and I want

> F1_USA_40__u

Does it has any function for this?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Strip all the non-alphanumeric characters, except the parentheses which should be replaced by underscores instead?

Comment: From the beginning of the word I want to remove the non-alphanumeric characters and in the words I want to replace with '_'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably `regexprep` which allows you to replace parts of a string using regular expressions:

```
s_new = regexprep(regexprep(s, '[()]', '_'), '[^A-Za-z0-9_]', '')
```

**Update**: based on your updated comment, this is probably what you want:

```
s_new = regexprep(regexprep(s, '^[^A-Za-z0-9_]*', ''), '[^A-Za-z0-9_]', '')
```

or:

```
s_new = regexprep(regexprep(s, '[^A-Za-z0-9_]', '_'), '^_*', '')
```

Comment: There is a typo in the first solution of your update. You should have a `'_'` instead of a `''` at the end. Also, using [cell array inputs for the expressions and replacement strings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexprep.html#f76-1152246) will allow you to make just one call to REGEXPREP.

Comment: The first solution refers to the stage when it was unclear what the OP wanted - I have assumed that he wants to replace parentheses with underscores and then strip everything that is not alphanumeric or an underscore. Also, thanks for the link, I didn't know about that. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the function [ISSTRPROP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isstrprop.html) to find the indices of alphanumeric characters and replace or remove the others accordingly:

```
>> str = '@#%%F1_USA(40)_u';           %# Sample string
>> index = isstrprop(str,'alphanum');  %# Find indices of alphanumeric characters
>> str(~index) = '_';                  %# Set non-alphanumeric characters to '_'
>> str = str(find(index,1):end)        %# Remove any leading '_'

str =

F1_USA_40__u                           %# Result
```

If you want to use [regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html) (which can get a little more complicated) then [the last suggestion from Tamas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816668/working-string-in-matlab/5816758#5816758) will work. However, it can be greatly simplified to the following:

```
str = regexprep(str,{'\W','^_*'},{'_',''});
```